# How to override PrimeFaces DataTable to support custom filter

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I want to override Primefaces default DataTableRenderer to support custom filter, by date, date range, select menu... just by adding attribute to column.

e.g to have date filter the syntax will be:

```
<m:dataTable value = "">
  <m:column filterType = "date">

  </m:column>
</m:dataTable>
```

I can modify the encodeFilter function in DataTableRenderer to add a calendar in place of the filter like this, but I don't know how to make the DataTable use this value to filter.

```
if (StringUtils.equals(filterType, "date")) {

    final Calendar inputDate = new Calendar();
    inputDate.setValue(column.getFilterValue());
    inputDate.encodeAll(context);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be much more easy just to create your own facelet tags for this purpose?

Comment: We already override p:dataTable and p:column to add more functions, so it would be more convenient to have new filterType attribute. But can you explain on the facelet tags?

Comment: e.g. for a "selectCheckBox-filter" I wrote this little facelet tag: http://www.codesend.com/view/c95201d29e4170241248996256595cd8/ it's far from perfect, but it fits my needs and maybe it's an interesting starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this. But since the filter is reused a lot across the system, that's why I want to make it an attribute of <m:column>.